# Search similar images solution with pHash

Tags: image, search, phash

A lot of images stored in database. I compute every image's hash with pHash and store the hash value into database.

How can I search the known image's similar images? Need I traversal every images stored in database and compute the distance with pHash?

Does there is a efficient way?

Any idea?

Comment: you can use knn-search that use some kind of tree.